# grub won't start ubuntu desktop automatically

Tags: grub2

After installing Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 `grub2` starts. when I select Ubuntu it drops me out at a initramfs prompt with some suggestions about changing the root or delay parameters. If I type exit at the prompt then Ubuntu starts with no issues. How do I configure grub2 to boot Ubuntu automatically? I've already tried all the options on my grub2 menu, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command and check to start the grub,

```
nano /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

After doing so check whether the GRUB has able to open the GRUB automatically,

```
 sudo gedit /etc/default/grub/
```

Hope the above helps.